# WSO2 API Manager 1.8.0 fails to import Swagger definition

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to import Swagger definition in WSO2 AM 1.8.0 while creating new API. But, the import fails with the exceptions in logs as below,

```
ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.import:jag} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 27 (/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/import.jag#25)

Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 27

Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 27
```

I'm using below configurations:

- Swagger-core_2.11-1.3.12
- Swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.11-1.3.12
- Swagger-annotations-1.3.12
- Tomcat 7
- JDK 1.7
- WSO2 API Manager 1.8.0

I create two simple restful services and add Swagger annotations to them. I can see doc in Swagger UI and can invoke them as well. I verify generated JSON for listing and resources and find it valid. But, when I try to import that definition in WSO2AM, it fails to do so.

What Swagger specification does WSO2 AM 1.8.0 support?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you can share the JSON that causes the failure?

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I'm able to overcome this problem. The file `wso2am-1.8.0\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\site\blocks\item-design\ajax\import.jag` has code which sends http requests and fetches json data in loop.
`var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 for(var i = 0; i < swaggerJson.apis.length; i++){
  xhr.open("GET", url + swaggerJson.apis[i].path);`
For some reason, it's unable to reuse XMLHttpRequest instance to send request. I moved XMLHttpRequest instance creation statement in a for loop and it worked.

Comment: Could this be probable bug fix, that can be added to WSO2AM source?

Comment: You should post that as the answer to the question. As for it being a bug fix, I don't know. Never used WSO2AM, but be sure to open an issue on the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to overcome this problem. The file **wso2am-1.8.0\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\site\blocks\ite‌​m-design\ajax\import.jag** has code which sends http requests and fetches json data in loop.

`var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  for(var i = 0; i < swaggerJson.apis.length; i++){
    xhr.open("GET", url + swaggerJson.apis[i].path);`

For some reason, it's unable to reuse XMLHttpRequest instance to send subsequent requests. I moved XMLHttpRequest instance creation statement in a for loop and it worked.

`//var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  for(var i = 0; i < swaggerJson.apis.length; i++){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // moved instance creation here
    xhr.open("GET", url + swaggerJson.apis[i].path);`